# FetchXML query to return all records owned by subordinates of current user

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I have a org that uses Managerial hierarchy to organize Employees (Users). They'd like a view for managers. This view should return all Open Opportunities owned by Users who are managed by the current user, OR managed by someone who is managed by the current user, OR managed by someone who is managed by someone who is managed by the current user. These 3 levels is are all that we need.

I've already developed a FetchXML query that returns all Projects owned by Users who are managed by the current user.

```
  <entity name="opportunity">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="estimatedvalue" />
    <attribute name="statuscode" />
    <attribute name="parentcontactid" />
    <attribute name="parentaccountid" />
    <attribute name="opportunityid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="owninguser" link-type="inner" alias="ad">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="parentsystemuserid" operator="eq-userid" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Below is an alternative that also doesn't work. This returns all Opportunities that are owned by someone who is managed by current user, which manages them self.

```
  <entity name="opportunity">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="estimatedvalue" />
    <attribute name="statuscode" />
    <attribute name="parentcontactid" />
    <attribute name="parentaccountid" />
    <attribute name="opportunityid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="owninguser" link-type="inner" alias="aa">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="parentsystemuserid" operator="eq-userid" />
      </filter>
      <link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="parentsystemuserid" link-type="inner" alias="ab">
        <filter type="and">
          <condition attribute="parentsystemuserid" operator="eq-userid" />
        </filter>
        <link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="parentsystemuserid" link-type="inner" alias="ac">
          <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="parentsystemuserid" operator="eq-userid" />
          </filter>
        </link-entity>
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the following owner operators:

- `eq-useroruserhierarchy`
- `eq-useroruserhierarchyandteams`
- `eq-useroruserteams`
- `eq-userteams`

From your description you might want `eq-useroruserhierarchy`

You use it like this:

```
<fetch top="50" >
  <entity name="opportunity" >
    <all-attributes/>
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="ownerid" operator="eq-useroruserhierarchy" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```